# IIS 7.5 Application Pool Recycle not letting method finish

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

I have 2 methods:

```
public void Stop(bool immediate)
{
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Shutdown detected. Immediate: " + immediate);
    Shutdown();
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Unregistering");
    HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
}

public void Shutdown()
{
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Preparing to stop UploadQueue");
    IsProcessing = false;

     //Set tasks to cancel to prevent queued tasks from parsing
     _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

     Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Waiting for " + _workerTasks.Count + " tasks to finish or cancel.");
     //Wait for tasks to finish
     Task.WaitAll(_workerTasks.Values.ToArray());

     Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Stopped UploadQueue");
}
```

The class is using the IRegisteredObject interface to receive the shutdown notification. In my log I get this:

```
2014-07-18 15:30:55,913,DEBUG,Shutdown detected. Immediate: False
2014-07-18 15:30:55,913,DEBUG,Preparing to stop UploadQueue
2014-07-18 15:30:55,913,DEBUG,Waiting for 35 tasks to finish or cancel.
...
bunch of stuff
...
2014-07-18 15:31:28,471,DEBUG,Shutdown detected. Immediate: True
2014-07-18 15:31:28,471,DEBUG,Preparing to stop UploadQueue
2014-07-18 15:31:28,471,DEBUG,Waiting for 0 tasks to finish or cancel.
2014-07-18 15:31:28,471,DEBUG,Stopped UploadQueue
2014-07-18 15:31:28,471,DEBUG,Unregistering
```

Why isn't it getting to the `Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Stopped UploadQueue");` the first time? it certainly seems like its cancelling the tasks and letting the ones that are running finish. (The task checks if its cancelled before running, otherwise does it's thing).

Comment: Maybe some task throws exception in the first case? So Logger.Log() method is not called this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **AggregationException:**
>
> At least one of the Task instances **was canceled** -or- an exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances. If a task was canceled, the AggregateException contains an OperationCanceledException in its InnerExceptions collection.

You are cancelling your Tasks via `_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();` and i assume that is causing at least one of them to throw an exception. You might be catching it in a higher level stackframe and disregarding it. Wrap `Task.WaitAll` inside a try-catch block:

```
public void Shutdown()
{
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Preparing to stop UploadQueue");
    IsProcessing = false;

    //Set tasks to cancel to prevent queued tasks from parsing
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Waiting for " + _workerTasks.Count + " tasks to finish or cancel.");

     try
     {
         //Wait for tasks to finish
         Task.WaitAll(_workerTasks.Values.ToArray());

         Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Stopped UploadQueue");
     }
     catch (AggregationException e)
     {
         // Recover from the exception
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 but note: _recover_ from the exception, don't **ignore** it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I always try/catch/swallow, it's the best for sure.

Comment: @Shawn: no, it's the worst.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sarcasm is also the best.

Comment: @Shawn: this is an international site. Many readers will not know you are being sarcastic.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Is sarcasm a distinctly English way of speaking?